# Find queue that had ready messages in past in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

On a RabbitMQ instance, how can I find which queue had ready messages in a time other than right now? For example, take a look at figure below:

[image: RabbitMQ Ready Messages]

On Queues tab, I can sort queues by Ready Messages, and see which queue has ready messages right now. But if there was just some short term misbehavior in my services some seconds ago, I would miss what queue it was.

Answer (score 0):

Those metrics are gathered/stored by the management plugin.
The stats provided by RabbitMQ are explained in [RabbitMQ metrics](https://www.rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html#rabbitmq-metrics)
RabbitMQ has several [resources](https://www.rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html#monitoring-tools) to integrate with different monitoring tools